# Getting ChromeCast session_error when trying to create a queue

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, queue, chromecast

I'm trying to resume a video on a cast device and need to set the startTime of one item.

I figured out that you need to set startTime on a queueItem and not the mediaInfo. loading a mediaInfo works fine but loading a queueList dose not, it throws a session_error and I don't know why.

> "A session could not be created, or a session was invalid."

```
const context = cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance();
const {SESSION_STATE_CHANGED} = cast.framework.CastContextEventType

// initiate session
cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().requestSession()

context.addEventListener(SESSION_STATE_CHANGED, () => {
  switch (event.sessionState) {
    case cast.framework.SessionState.SESSION_STARTED:
      const castSession = cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession()
      const queueItem = new chrome.cast.media.QueueItem(createMediaInfo(source));
      queueItem.startTime = 50
      const itemsToAdd = [queueItem]
      const request = new chrome.cast.media.QueueLoadRequest(itemsToAdd);

      castSession.loadMedia(request).then(console.log, console.error)
      // Throws session_error --------^

    break
    case cast.framework.SessionState.SESSION_RESUMED:
      // update ui 
    break
    case cast.framework.SessionState.SESSION_ENDED:
      // update ui 
    break
  }
})
```

using the `LoadRequest` works fine but I can't set a startTime or set up a playlist with that.

```
const mediaInfo = createMediaInfo(source)
const request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
castSession.loadMedia(request).then(console.log, console.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apperently you need to have one media active before you can start using the queuing api...?

> The Cast Receiver SDK maintains the queue and responds to operations on the queue as long as the queue has at least one item currently active (playing or paused).

So I can't transfer my hole playlist in one go